# Add a column according to other columns in a matrix. [python]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, multiple-columns

I got a matrix of the form:

```
      1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
1      0    0    0    1
2      0    0    1    0
3      1    0    0    0
4      0    1    0    0
5      1    0    0    0
6      0    0    0    0
7      1    0    0    0
```

I want to add another column in the matrix where its value will be 1 only if every other value is 0 and 0 otherwise. So visually i want this:

```
      1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
1      0    0    0    1   0
2      0    0    1    0   0
3      1    0    0    0   0
4      0    1    0    0   0
5      1    0    0    0   0
6      0    0    0    0   1
7      1    0    0    0   0
```

Comment: [`df['5.0'] = (~df.any(axis=1)).astype(int)`](https://uscript.co/public/Google_108617488638529745626/python/38bc6825.py)

Comment: or `df['5.0'] = df.sum(axis=1).eq(0).astype(int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try something different. we can take sun acriss axis 1 and convert to `np.sign` then subtract that result with 1 which converts 0 to 1 and 1 to 0.

```
df['5.0'] = 1-np.sign(df.sum(1))
```

Or with `df.any(axis=1)`

```
df['5.0'] = 1-df.any(1)
```

---

```
print(df)

   1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0
1    0    0    0    1    0
2    0    0    1    0    0
3    1    0    0    0    0
4    0    1    0    0    0
5    1    0    0    0    0
6    0    0    0    0    1
7    1    0    0    0    0
```

If the a row can have just one 1 or less just do;

```
df['5.0'] = 1-df.sum(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

this must do the job :

```
df['05']=(df.sum(axis=1)==0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use df.apply to create a new series then assign like this:

```
df[5.0] = df.apply(lambda row: 1 if all(i == 0 for i in row) else 0, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the matrix to Dataframe function:

```
 matrixA = {}
 matrixA['1'] = [0, 0, 0, 1]
 matrixA['2'] = [0, 1, 0, 0]
 matrixA['3'] = [0, 0, 1, 1]
 matrixA['4'] = [0, 1, 1, 1]
 df = pd.DataFrame(matrixA)
```

after that add a lambda function

```
df['5'] = df.apply(lambda x: 
     get_sum_of_1(list(x)),axis=1).reset_index(drop=True).copy()
```

and the calculated row function will be:

```
def get_sum_of_1(row):
    return row.count(1) % 2
```